# Convert Windows FILTIME value to .NET DateTime

Tags: c#

We have a database from third party software where it has LastModifiedDate field stored as WINDOWS filetime. 
We need to conver this to .NET DateTime format and supricingly it has -ve values.

.NET's DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc method will work for +ve filetime values btu for -ve values it will not work.

How do i convert -ve filttime value to DateTime format ?
Sample valules:
-ve value : -9094325347534722713
+ve value : 8872694038044633872

Answer (score 4):

[DateTime.FromFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletime.aspx)

Comment: Darin, this method will not work for -ve values. It throws following exception : "Not a valid Win32 FileTime.
Parameter name: fileTime"

Answer (score 3):

You are getting garbage values from the database.  The maximum date representable in DateTime is Dec 31 of the year 9999.  The corresponding FILETIME value is 2650467743999999999.  Negative FILETIME values cannot convert, you'll get an exception when you try to use DateTime.FromFileTime().

Tackle this problem at the root, there's a bug in the program that generates the dbase data.  Probably a mistake when sign-extending FILETIME.dwLowDateTime.  You already saw this in the MSDN forum thread.

Comment: There is nothing i can do about storage of FILETIME in database, We are working on some product which extends SharePoint functionality and the datbase table from where i get these values are of SharePoint and we dont have control on how these values should be stored.So, i need some solution which takes this -ve value as input and return me the correct datetime format value.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same issue recently. When converting a FILETIME into a DateTimeOffset I was getting negative values causing the FromFileTime method to throw and exception

`Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Not a valid Win32 FileTime.`

I discovered my mistake was in the conversion. Here's the **bad** line of code

```cs
long time = (ft.dwHighDateTime << 32) + ft.dwLowDateTime;
```

I added a cast to 'long' so that it treats the value as 64-bit before the bit-shift

```cs
long time = ((long)ft.dwHighDateTime << 32) + ft.dwLowDateTime;
```

Now the dates are coming out correctly as expected.

Here's the complete function for reference

```cs
static string ConvertFileTime(System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ft)
{
    long time = ((long)ft.dwHighDateTime << 32) + ft.dwLowDateTime;
    var dto = DateTimeOffset.FromFileTime(time).ToLocalTime();
    return dto.ToString();
}
```

I suggest double checking the FILETIME conversion to make sure it's translating the high and low 32-bit integers into a positive 64-bit value.